# Gulp Dest is Ignoring Subdirectories

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

### Solution

Add `return` before the `gulp.src` because `gulp.src` returns a stream asynchronously and the return will indicate to the task runner when the stream has finished processing.

### Question

Here is my gulp task for simply moving images from src to dist (this file is saved as gulp_tasks/images.js):

```
const gulp        = require('gulp'),
      browserSync = require('browser-sync');

module.exports = (gulp, config , isDist) => {
    return () => {
         gulp.src(config.src.img)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dist.img))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream({stream: true}))
    };
};
```

Here is (a stripped version) of my gulpfile.js that has all of the relevant functions/includes:

```
const gulp    = require('gulp'),
      argv    = require('yargs').argv,
      isDist  = argv.prod ? true : false,
      config  = {
            src: {
                img: 'src/img/**/*'
            },
            dist: {    
                img: 'dist/img',
            }
        };

function getTask(task) {
    return require('./gulp_tasks/' + task)(gulp, config, isDist);
}

gulp.task('img', getTask('images'));
```

To run this task, I use `gulp img`.

It seems that my gulp isn't going into the subdirectories correctly, despite having (what I think is) the correct glob pattern.

Running this task on a folder with the following structure (assuming we're already inside of src/img):

```
├── a.jpg
├── b
│   ├── c.jpg
│   ├── d
│   │   ├── e.jpg
```

Results in the following output in dist/img:

```
├── a.jpg
├── b
│   ├── c.jpg
│   ├── d
```

I was wondering how I could ensure that e.jpg is correctly transferred as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I've just tried your setup and everything seems fine. This is the code I've used: `gulp.task('default', () => gulp.src('src/img/**/*').pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img')));`. We might need more of your gulpfile to find out the problem.

Comment: @NelsonYeung I've added the relevant part of my gulpfile to the original post. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Mine is still working with your new code. Hmmm... Which version of gulp are you using? And also try using [gulp-debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-debug) to see what's going through your pipeline. I feel like you are actually removing that file elsewhere but we'll see from your `gulp-debug` output.

Comment: @NelsonYeung I'm using gulp v3.9.0. I'll run gulp-debug when I get a chance, but I'm pretty sure I'm not removing the file elsewhere. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @NelsonYeung With gulp-debug, it looks like the transfer task just randomly stops in the middle. Not really sure how to go about debugging this one.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could create a demo repository that can produce this error, because I've literally copied all your code and directory setup above and it's all working. Just one more suggestion, though, is to try this glob pattern `src/img/**` instead.

Comment: @NelsonYeung I managed to solve the problem after adding the gulp-debug; adding `return` before `gulp.src` fixed the problem. I noticed that the debug logs would end early without the function necessarily completing, and so adding the return resolved the async return of gulp.src.